# nginx - The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, nginx

my site is responding me *The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later.*

Any ideas what I did wrong? Thank you.

This config is working on another site, but not this one. I don't know why.

```
    server {
                listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

                root /var/www/vhosts/site.com;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;

                # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
                server_name server.com;

                error_log /var/log/nginx/err.com.error.log;

                ## Compression
                gzip              on;
                gzip_buffers      16 8k;
                gzip_comp_level   4;
                gzip_http_version 1.0;
                gzip_min_length   1280;
                gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript im$
                gzip_vary         on;

                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

                location / {
                        # if you're just using wordpress and don't want extra rewrites
                        # then replace the word @rewrites with /index.php
                        # try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                }

                # Allow access to root index.php
#        location ~ ^/index\.php {
        location ~ \.php {
                include     fastcgi_params;
#                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
#                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|pdf|xlsx|xls|docx|doc|zip|rar)$ {
                 access_log off;
                 expires max;
        }

        #
        # 404 error page
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;

        #
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
               root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Share access and error log first of all please.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, I've just solved it. Uncommented fastcgi_split and fastcgi_param so it's solved now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong fastcgi_pass :) I just had to change it to `127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: It would be a better answer if you would've include some more details about how you changed it